# Github Actions CI: Not running on push for feature branches

Tags: github, github-actions

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@wkrzywiec/github-actions-for-android-first-approach-f616c24aa0f9) to run [my unit tests on Github](https://github.com/qbalsdon/currency_list_app). I have it on both master and feature branch, but it's not firing when I push to the feature branch.

```
 on:
   push:
     branches:
       - '*'
       - '!master'
       - '!release*'
```

However if I follow the cron-based example from [the docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/configuring-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-with-events):

```
 on:
   schedule:
     - cron:  '0 * * * *'
```

It will run but I want this to be for pull requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags):

```
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/heads
    branches-ignore:
      - master
      - release*
```